# HTML Help, need easy way to change text on my site

Tags: html, css, text

i am making a website that will feature many articles that will always be changing, i am trying to find a way to quickly change the text in these articles as i am the only person who knows the code in the company.

I was thinking of having a text document or something that has the articles text and when it gets changed so does the text on the site.I just dont know how to implement this.

sorry if its hard to understand what i mean, im not too familiar with sleep these days.

Comment: as i am on a time crunch i clearly displayed in the HTML file where to change the text. Should do for the time being untill i have more time to try those options. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Time crunch? Well unless you show what you have already tried and what has worked, I doubt you will get response. Did you start with some design in mind and corresponding technology stack that you would want to use...your requirement can be implemented in many ways, it is very open ended. To us it reads like, I need to go from A to B how I should go? Well what's your limitation, can you fly or drive or bus would be ok...what is needed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any dynamic server code like the other answers are suggesting. Either a "static site generator" (there are uncountably many, but that should give you something to Google if my main answer doesn't satisfy you) or a client-side scripting.

XSLT was *designed* for this exact problem. It can be run client-side or server-side with `xsltproc` (for compatibility with dumb clients). XSLT 1.0 is well-supported by all common browsers, though if you need EXSLT extensions in IE you had to add shims. Note that Webkit-based browsers can't do XSLT on `file://` URLs, either set up a local HTTP server or use Firefox.

I have a minimal example site set up here that includes multiple files in 
one page: https://o11c.github.io/foo-test/foo-root.xml

> foo-style.xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
>   <xsl:template match="/index">
>     <html>
>     <body>
>       <h2>Merge test</h2>
>       <table border="1">
>         <tr>
>           <th>Attr</th>
>           <th>Value</th>
>         </tr>
>         <xsl:apply-templates select="document(include/@name)"/>
>       </table>
>     </body>
>     </html>
>   </xsl:template>
>   <xsl:template match="root">
>     <xsl:for-each select="foo">
>       <tr>
>         <td><xsl:value-of select="@x"/></td>
>         <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
>       </tr>
>     </xsl:for-each>
>   </xsl:template>
>   <xsl:template name="identity">
>     <xsl:copy>
>       <xsl:for-each select="node()|@*">
>         <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
>       </xsl:for-each>
>     </xsl:copy>
>   </xsl:template>
> </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```
>
> foo-root.xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="foo-style.xslt"?>
> <index>
>   <include name="foo-1.xml"/>
>   <include name="foo-2.xml"/>
> </index>
> ```
>
> foo-1.xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <root>
>   <foo x="a">aa</foo>
>   <foo x="b">bb</foo>
>   <foo x="c">cc</foo>
> </root>
> ```
>
> foo-2.xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <root>
>   <foo x="d">dd</foo>
>   <foo x="e">ee</foo>
>   <foo x="f">ff</foo>
> </root>
> ```

Further resources:

- [XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/)
- [XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) - in particular the [function reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib)
- [EXSLT extensions](http://exslt.org/) - `node-set` in particular is very useful.
- [`xsltproc` webpage](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use wordpress, if you are building the site from scratch and not adding to an existing one. This will allow you to edit articles in a user friendly interface that will allow you to style the text and will be easier for other people in the company to edit as well. It's very fast to set up.

Or you could just keep the written text in the HTML file itself, but this may make it harder to maintain and style, and those not technical savvy may not be able to edit it or will end up breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you might do this using php and Mysql
You can easily display save the articles in mysql and you could create a simple user interface for the people respnsible for editing the code to edit it too easy